# How to conduct a meta-analysis on ICCs (i.e., test-retest reliability)?

Tags: r, meta-analysis, reliability, intraclass-correlation, reliability-meta-analysis

I have calculated two-way single consistency ICCs in R using the irr package. There are multiple ICCs representing test-retest reliability across these time points.

Is there a way to compute a meta-analysis on ICCs in R? Or to convert ICCs into a different coefficient (e.g. Pearson R) in order to conduct a meta-analysis? Converting ICCs into a different coefficient seems challenging potentially because not all ICCs are the same (e.g., "average" ICCs will be higher than "single" ICCs).

Does anyone have any insight on conducting meta-analyses on ICCs?